# Reduce gap between two groups in matplotlib bar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have used the below code to generate the attached graph. My issue is that there is too much white space between the two groups of bars. I know I could reduce the gap by increasing bar width, but that's not what I require. I need to keep the bar width same as other graphs that I have generated earlier.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np


sns.set()
sns.set_style("dark")
sns.set_style("whitegrid",{"xtick.major.size": 5})
sns.set(font_scale=1.2)
plt.figure(figsize=(2,6))
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

n_groups = 2


skip=[0.651]
skip.append(sum([0.819335,0.818205])/len([0.819335,0.818205]))

Glove=[0.655]
Glove.append(sum([0.768675,0.835844])/len([0.768675,0.835844]))

RNN=[0.629]
RNN.append(sum([0.768675,0.773007])/len([0.768675,0.773007]))

Global=[0.635]
Global.append(sum([0.759134,0.764281])/len([0.759134,0.764281]))

Cross=[0.665]
Cross.append(sum([0.768675,0.838481])/len([0.768675,0.838481]))
Dist=[0.61]
Dist.append(sum([0.753107,0.755493])/len([0.753107,0.755493]))

#Comparion of Brain Bench Vs Rest
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.05
opacity = 1.0
#('Global Context', 'Skip-Gram',    'RNN',  'Cross-Lingual',    'Glove',    'Non-Distributional','Skip-Gram-Italian')

rects1 = plt.bar(index, skip, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='#581845',
                 label='Skip-Gram')

rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, Glove, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='#FF5733',
                 label='Glove')


rects3 = plt.bar(index + bar_width + bar_width, RNN, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='#000080',
                 label='RNN')

rects4 = plt.bar(index + bar_width + bar_width+bar_width, Global, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='#800080',
                 label='Global Context')

rects5 = plt.bar(index + bar_width + bar_width+bar_width+bar_width, Cross, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='#808000',
                 label='Cross-Lingual')

rects6 = plt.bar(index + bar_width + bar_width+bar_width+bar_width+bar_width, Dist, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='#FFC300',
                 label='Non-Dist')








#algo = ('BrainBench','WS-353','WS-353-SIM', 'WS-353-REL','MEN','MTurk-771')
algo = ( 'BrainBench V1.0','BrainBench V2.0')
algo_len = np.arange(len(algo))
#plt.xticks(index + 0.15, ( 'BrainBench','WS-353','WS-353-SIM', 'WS-353-REL','MEN','MTurk-771'))
plt.xticks(index+bar_width, ( 'BrainBench V1.0','BrainBench V2.0'))
plt.ylim(0.55,0.88)
#sns.plt.title('2 vs. 2 Accuracy for Concrete/Abstract Words in Italian fMRI').set_fontsize('12')
sns.plt.title('Comparison of BrainBench Versions').set_fontsize('12')
sns.plt.ylabel('Correlation').set_fontsize('12')




plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.20)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
# plt.xticks(rotation=15)
#plt.show()
plt.savefig("/Users/Dhanush/Desktop/Versions.png", dpi=300)
```

[image: Two groups of bar separated by large gap]

The basis issue here is the large gap between the two groups. I need the two groups to be separated by a single bar-width

Comment: Wow that's a lot of code.  Can you slim it down into just a minimal example of your problem?

Comment: I did the changes @chriz suggested, that's all the code needed to generate the above graph

Comment: People here really do have a culture of downvoting if they don't know the answer. There are no questions like this and most don't even know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the code to get the desired results.
Replaced the index and bar width in below code snippet with custom positions in with a list. Here the list indicates the exact positions to plot the bar. I gave for first bar 0.1 and second bar at 0.5. Each bar width is 0.05 and there are 6 bars. So 0.1+ 6*0.05 + 0.1 as gap between two groups which gives me 0.5 as starting position for 2nd bar plot of skip-gram.

Before

```
rects1 = plt.bar(index, skip, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='#581845',
                 label='Skip-Gram')
```

Changed to

```
rects1 = plt.bar([0.1, 0.5], skip, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,align='center',
                 color='#581845',
                 label='Skip-Gram')
```

[image]